# Mysql convert an int to MAC

Tags: mysql, function, int

I have some data that converts which has a 2 columns one column has IP and it contains values which are integers.I used the following function in my mysql query.Is there a function i can use to to convert my mac column which contains integers and data type is bigint to MAC address.

```
SELECT  INET_NTOA(ip_address) AS myip,mymac 
FROM table1
```

Comment: what algorithm did you used to store the MAC address are bigint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you have stored the MAC address by suppressing all separators and converting the resulting HEX number into int, the conversion from this int to a human readable MAC address would be:

```
function int2macaddress($int) {
    $hex = base_convert($int, 10, 16);
    while (strlen($hex) < 12)
        $hex = '0'.$hex;
    return strtoupper(implode(':', str_split($hex,2)));
}
```

The function is taken from http://www.onurguzel.com/storing-mac-address-in-a-mysql-database/

The MySQL version for this function:

```
delimiter $$
create function itomac (i BIGINT)
    returns char(20) 
    language SQL
begin
    declare temp CHAR(20);
    set temp = lpad (hex (i), 12, '0');
    return concat (left (temp, 2),':',mid(temp,3,2),':',mid(temp,5,2),':',mid(temp,7,2),':',mid(temp,9,2),':',mid(temp,11,2));
end;
$$
delimiter ;
```

You can also do it directly in SQL, like this:

```
select
    concat (left (b.mh, 2),':',mid(b.mh,3,2),':',mid(b.mh,5,2),':',mid(b.mh,7,2),':',mid(b.mh,9,2),':',mid(b.mh,11,2))
from (
    select lpad (hex (a.mac_as_int), 12, '0') as mh
    from (
        select 1234567890 as mac_as_int
    ) a
) b
```

Comment: Is there a mysql function I can use to convert bigint to a MAC address. I want to add it to my mysql select statement. Am not using php.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sorry for the PHP example; I've updated the answer with MySQL function example.

Comment: Thank you for the solution it has given me a good lead. am trying to integrate the SQL directly in my original select statement but am struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`HEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_hex):

> For a numeric argument ***`N`***, [`HEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) returns a hexadecimal string representation of the value of ***`N`*** treated as a longlong ([`BIGINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/integer-types.html)) number.

Therefore, in your case:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(ip_address) AS myip, HEX(mymac)
FROM   table1
```

Note that this won't insert byte delimiters, such as colon characters.