# Convert mac adress from varchar to bigint(6) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mac-address

I need convert a lot of mac addresses in mysql database from varchar format to bigint(6).
I know that mac address C404158996CD - is 215521820251853.
What is a proper function to do this? I've tried to use hex() for this but it return 433430343135383939364344 for the same mac address.

Comment: Did you check `conv` function something as `select CONV('C404158996CD', 16, 10) as addr; ` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C404158996CD is a hexadecimal number, 215521820251853 a decimal. HEX(215521820251853) = C404158996CD, not the other way around.

You need `CONV('C404158996CD', 16,10)` ("convert 'C404158996CD' from base 16 to base 10")

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.onurguzel.com/storing-mac-address-in-a-mysql-database/). Here they are converting MAC address to `bigint`. You can do something like this :

```
select
concat (left (b.mh, 2),':',mid(b.mh,3,2),':',mid(b.mh,5,2),':',mid(b.mh,7,2),':',mid(b.mh,9,2),':',mid(b.mh,11,2))
from (
    select lpad (hex (a.mac_as_int), 12, '0') as mh
    from (
        select 1234567890 as mac_as_int
    ) a
) b
```

This [stackoverflow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588665/mysql-convert-an-int-to-mac) is explaining it in detail.

Alternatively, you can also use `MySQL`'s `conv` function too